# Distribute application without installing mono

Tags: mono, mkbundle

I want to distribute my c# application to each computer on a linux cluster so that I can run it without having to install mono on each computer.

I have spent hours trying to get mkbundle to work, but it doesn't bundle properly (I am unable to run the application on another machine that doesn't have mono installed).

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: how are you running mkbundle? have you read: http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications

Answer (score -4):

In this scenario it might be better to install mono seperately - updating your app will be easier if you don't have to include mono every time. The exact setup will depend a certain amount on what sort of linux you are using, but even if you are doing a source build there are ways to make the mono installation relatively painless.

Comment: mkbundle is exactly the point here, gentuba wants to distribute his app without relying upon a specific mono at the other end.

Comment: For end user distribution that would be the case, but this question appears to be about distribution across your own cluster - you can add mono as part of the basic server setup, and updating the app is a simple assembly upload rather than complex install logic.